# Remove the "Dropdown" icon if the dropdown is disabled in angular2-multiselect

Tags: css, angular

I am using angular2-multiselect in an angular 7 application. I have a scenario where I have to remove the dropdown icon if the dropdown is disabled. I can remove the icon by setting display none to .c-angle-down but I want to remove it only on some condition ( when the dropdown is disabled ).

```
<angular2-multiselect [(ngModel)]="committeeModel.subType" #subType2="ngModel" name="subType" (ngModelChange)="changeInValueSubType($event)" id="subType" [data]="subType" [settings]="subTypedropdownSettings" subType> </angular2-multiselect>
```

Comment: If you could please add some of your code then we might be able to help.

Comment: how you are removing using c-angle-down?
then you can maintain two settings object and apply on ng-if or something